# Grouping Dates By Quarter with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am currently running a query where I am grouping by either Month or Day or Year.  How can I Group by Quarter?

```
 group by DATE_FORMAT(o.PaidDate,'%Y-%m')
```

i.e.

```
 group by DATE_FORMAT(o.PaidDate,'%Q')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL provides functions to extract the year and quarter from a date, you can use them.

```
GROUP BY YEAR(o.PaidDate), QUARTER(o.PaidDate)
```

Comment: Follow up actually... This works if I do January to March and even April to June, but when I do July to September, instead of showing one grouped row, it shows 2 rows.  Any ideas?

Comment: This query gives me a single grouped row:
SELECT COUNT(ID) AS Total FROM orders WHERE PaidDate > '2011-01-01 00:00:00' AND PaidDate < '2011-04-01 00:00:00' GROUP BY YEAR(PaidDate), FLOOR((MONTH(PaidDate)-1)/4)

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with sample data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sure thing.  Here you go.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35526/4  As you can see instead of producing only one row,  (grouped by quarter) it is in 2 separate rows and I am not sure why.

Comment: Actually, it looks like the answer is just: GROUP BY YEAR(PaidDate), Quarter (PaidDate);

Comment: Stupid mistake, I should have been dividing by 3, not 4. But using `QUARTER` is obviously better.

Comment: You get the prize anyway!  :). Thanks for your help.